# Eclipse CDT indexer adding unwanted quotes to symbol

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In a project, I am using separate header files to specify parameters for separate configurations.  For example, `config1.h` and `config2.h`.  I have created separate build configurations in Eclipse for each configuration and added symbol `PARAM_H_FILE` assigned either `PARAM_H_FILE=config1.h` or `PARAM_H_FILE=config2.h` in Eclipse as a defined symbol for the respective build configuration.  In order to include this file, I have added the following lines to a common header file in the project:

```
#define QT(filename)    #filename    //!< Convert filename to string
#define QUOTE(filename) QT(filename) //!< Expand filename string

// Include header file.
#include QUOTE(PARAM_H_FILE) // Include vehicle definitions
```

The compiler expands this to `#include "config1.h"` or `include "config2.h"` as desired and compiles with no errors or warnings.  However, the Eclipse CDT indexer expands this to `#include "\"config1.h\""` or `#include "\"config1.h\""`, resulting in detected errors any time the macros defined in `config1.h` or `config2.h` are referenced in the code.

Also, I found that if I replace the above code with the following, then Eclipse does not detect any errors, but the project compiles with errors:

```
#include QUOTE(PARAM_H_FILE) // Include vehicle definitions
```

Is there any way to specify the header file name as a defined symbol in Eclipse that will prevent the indexer from identifying errors and allow the project to build.

I have tried formatting the symbol definition as: `PARAM_H_FILE=config1.h`, `PARAM_H_FILE='config1.h'`, `PARAM_H_FILE='"config1.h"'` and `PARAM_H_FILE="config1.h"` and nothing seems to work.

As a point of reference, I am using is MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5 in Windows and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0).

Comment: Sounds like Eclipse/CDT bug. Should be reported if not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating further, I found that this was being caused by an `&quot;` added before and after the symbol assigned value in the .cproject XML file.  This may have been added by an older version of Eclipse.  In Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0), the quotation mark indicated by `&quot;` is not visible in the Project Properties window.

For example, the XML file may read:

`<listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;PARAM_H_FILE=config.h&quot;"/>`,

But the Project Properties reads:

`VC_PARAM_H_FILE=config.h` instead of `VC_PARAM_H_FILE="config.h"`.

The easiest way to remove `&quot;` manually from the .cproject XML file.